# Вектор ссылок С++

Tags: c++

Изучаю классы в C++. В следующем коде я хочу реализовать общую функцию updateAge(), которая у каждого элемента класса People (т.е. добавленного в вектор) вызывает одноимённую функцию класса updateAge, которая увеличивает у всех возраст на 1.

В общем, хотел добавить эти элементы в вектор для работы с ними с помощью цикла.

```
#include <pch.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


class People {
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    People(string fName = "Noname", int fAge = 0) {
        name = fName;
        age = fAge;
    }
    void updateAge() {
        age++;
    }
    void hello() {
        cout << "Hello, my name is " << name << " and I am " << age << " years old!" << endl << endl;
    }
};

// Прототипы функций

void updateAge(vector<People> vec);
void hello(vector<People> vec);

int main() {
    int year = 0;
    People people("Maxim", 28);
    people.hello();
    People &rPeople = people;

    People secPeople;
    secPeople.hello();
    People &rSecPeople = secPeople;

    vector<People> vec;
    vec.push_back(rPeople);
    vec.push_back(rSecPeople);

    year++; // Год проходит и возраст всех People увеличивается :>
    updateAge(vec);
    hello(vec);
    return 0;
}
void updateAge(vector<People> vec) { // Обновление возраста(age) у каждого элемента класса People
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        vec[i].updateAge();
    }
}
void hello(vector<People> vec) { // Выполнение у всех элементов класса People функции hello()
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        vec[i].hello();
    }
}
```

Проблема в добавлении элементов в вектор. Элементы вроде как копируются в вектор, а значит при их изменении в векторе сами они не меняются.

Хотел реализовать с помощью добавления в вектор ссылок на эти элементы, но что-то не получилось. Как реализовать это?

Comment: Попробуйте [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Comment: Не понял. Что именно вы хотите менять? Содержимое вектора `vec` или объекты `secPeople` и `people`?

Comment: @AnT, функция updateAge должна увеличивать возраст(age) всех объектов(в данном случае people и secPeople) на 1.

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Ну так... Это совсем другая задача. Такие вещи надо объяснять сразу. Непонятно только, зачем вам такое понадобилось.

Comment: @AnT, у этих людей(People) есть возраст(age). Там в коде есть строчка year++ (типа год проходит). После этого у всех людей нужно увеличить возраст на единицу.

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Ваш код увеличивает возраст у людей *в векторе*, а не возраст каких-то совершенно посторонних людей `people` и `secPeople`. Хотите увеличить возраст `people` и `secPeople` - делайте это напрямую. Почему вы хотите работать с совершенно отдельными объектами  `people` и `secPeople` через посредство вектора - вот это мне не ясно.

Comment: @AnT, ну, чтобы не делать это каждому объекту. В цикле же легче, но цикл не может работать тут без вектора. Вдруг объектов будет много и функций, которые работают с ними тоже. Для того и вектор предназначался. Теперь единственная задача, это передать в вектор ссылки на объекты, чтобы можно было их менять оттуда.

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Вот именно - объектов может быть много! Поэтому создавайте их сразу в контейнере. В векторе, например. Пусть они там и живут всегда. Не надо никаких `people` и `secPeople` россыпью посреди  кода. Зачем вам эти `people` и `secPeople`? У вас уже есть ваш `vec` - вот это и есть ваши `People`. Пусть они там и живут всегда - внутри `vec`. А создавать россыпь независимых объектов и затем думать, как с ними работать через вектор - это странное занятие. Такое бывает нужно, но оно нужно по объективным причинам. Зачем это понадобилось вам - я в упор не вижу.

Comment: Немного не в тему вопроса, но не проще ли в объектах класса хранить дату рождения, а age считать и возвращать с помощью одноимённого метода класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется ваш вектор не меняется. У вас во все функции (`updateAge` и `hello`) передаются *копии* вектора и работа идет с копиями. Передавайте ссылки или указатели на векторы, если вы хотите менять сами оригинальные векторы, а не их копии.

---

Если же вы хотите, чтобы через вектор менялись ваши оригинальные объекты `secPeople` и `people`, то это совсем другое дело. В такой ситуации вам нужен вектор ссылок или указателей. Вектор ссылок можно создать путем указания `std::reference_wrapper<People>` в качестве типа элемента.

Comment: Да, мне стоило на код в вопросе повнимательнее глянуть :)

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Только вот не понял, разве ссылка в копированном векторе не остаётся направленной на тот же элемент?

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Какая "ссылка"? У вас нет никаких ссылок. У вас в векторе хранятся сами объекты. Откуда вообще взялась тема каких-то "ссылок"?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Вам предлагают передавать ссылки/указатели на векторы объектов, а не на векторы ссылок.

Comment: @AnT, помогло, т.к. я добавил передачу ссылки на вектор в функцию. Я спрашивал про ссылки rPeople и rSecPeople, которые находятся в векторе.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Когда вы используете ссылку как параметр `push_back()`, в вектор попадает *копия* объекта, на который ссылается эта ссылка. С тем уже успехом вы могли бы передавать объект сразу в `push_back()`. Если вы хотите хранить в векторе не объекты, а ссылки/указатели на объекты, то в треугольных скобках в `vector<...>` должно быть написано не `People`, а что-то другое. Например `std::reference_wrapper<People>`, как предложили в комментариях, либо `People *`.

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Ваши ссылки `rPeople` и `rSecPeople` вообще ни на что не влияют и в векторе не находятся. У вас в векторе лежат самостоятельные объекты, а не ссылки. Нет никакой разницы между `vec.push_back(rPeople);` и `vec.push_back(people);`.

Answer (score 0):

Поместить в вектор ссылки не получится. Используй вместо них указатели.

Comment: Где вы увидели помещение ссылок в векторы???

Comment: @AnT, в последнем абзаце вопроса: _"Хотел реализовать с помощью добавления в вектор ссылок на эти элементы, но что-то не получилось. Как реализовать это?"_ И ещё в заголовке: _"Вектор ссылок С++"_.

Answer (score 0):

@Василий Пупкин а вы пробовали так писать ?

```
// Обновление возраста(age) у каждого элемента класса People
void updateAge(vector<People>& vec)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        vec[i].updateAge();
    }
}
```